# Jenkins Maven build with plan files push to artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I have a Jenkins build which has 2 requirements.

1. maven build(.war) that pushes war to snapshot or release on artifactory
2. Also push plan(.xml) files to 'plan' repository on artifactory - This needs to have the pom version (from pom.xml) in the path.

   [image: artifactory - xml]

I am having trouble replacing the $POM-VERSION in the path with the pom version.
What I have tried so far

#### Solution 1

Jenkins Maven Build - I don't seem to get an option to upload the plan files to artifactory with this.

#### Solution 2

Jenkins Freestyle Project - I can execute the maven build and upload the plans but pom-version is not available in freestyle

#### Solution 3

Jenkins Maven Build passing the pom version as a parameter to a freestyle build. This all ties together but the artifactory plugin does not replace the parameter in the path (As you can see above) - It seems it will work for environment variables but not parameters.
[image: deployment details]

Any ideas are welcome on how to workaround this or if anybody has any other suggested approaches. Or maybe I am missing something simple with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The env inject plugin looks to have resolved this for solution 3